# Remove from map from List<map<key,value>> if key belongs in the list

Tags: java, spring

I have a `List<Map<key,value>>`. I want to remove it from the list if the key exist in List

For example:

Input: `List<Map<a,1>,Map<b,2>,Map<c,3>>` (here  is a Map) , `List<a,d,e>`

Explanation: Since, key in map `<a,1>` exists in the `List<a,d,e>`, I want to remove Map from the `List<Map<a,1>,Map<b,2>,Map<c,3>>`

Output: `List<Map<b,2>,Map<c,3>>`

Comment: your question is very unclear and doesn't specify any thing about `map` as you wrote in description

Comment: Please list your problem properly by listing the code.

Comment: Please make your question more clear

Comment: Sorry for the confusion caused

Comment: List<a,d,e> this equal to List<String>. in your case List will have list of maps like List<map<a,1>,map<b,2>,map<c,3>>

Comment: Is it a list of maps, or just a list of pairs?

Comment: `List<Map<a,1>,Map<b,2>,Map<c,3>>` is meaningless in Java, `List` takes only one type parameter, not 3. It is not at all clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Its a list of Maps

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you could use java streams api, and do something like this:

```
public class Mapping {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        List<Map<String,Integer>> db = new LinkedList<Map<String,Integer>>();
        Map<String,Integer> item = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
        item.put("a", 1);
        item.put("b", 2);
        item.put("c", 3);
        db.add(item);

        List<String> excludeList = Arrays.asList("a");

        List<Map<String,Integer>> newDb = db.stream().map(sample->{
            Map<String,Integer> newSample = new HashMap<String,Integer>(sample); //we do not mutate original elements
            excludeList.forEach(key->newSample.remove(key));
            return newSample;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(db); //[{a=1, b=2, c=3
        System.out.println(newDb); //[{b=2, c=3}]
    }

}
```

in this fashion, you keep both original and new filtered lists

Answer (score 0):

try this, if you want to check the exclude key with list of maps

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    List<String> removeList = Arrays.asList("a","d","e");
    List<Map<String, Integer>> maps = new ArrayList<>();
    //Map1
    Map<String, Integer> map1 = new HashMap<>();
    map1.put("a", 1);
    map1.put("b", 2);
    map1.put("c", 3);
    maps.add(map1);

    //Map2
    Map<String, Integer> map2 = new HashMap<>();
    map2.put("e", 1);
    map2.put("f", 2);
    map2.put("g", 3);
    maps.add(map2);

    for(String string : removeList)
    {
        for(Map<String, Integer> eachMap: maps)
        {
            eachMap.remove(string);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(maps);

}
```